# How can I make a constant static immutable instance of a class?

Tags: c#

I have a simple class that represents 3 dimensional coordinates called `Coord3` that simply has x, y, and z `int` values.

I want to declare a static constant variable `Coord3.zero` where x, y, and z are set to 0.

I have attempted this with:

```
public static readonly Coord3 zero = new Coord3(0, 0, 0);
```

However I found that this variable can be changed. For example if I do

```
Coord3 coord = Coord3.zero;
coord.x = 5;
```

this actually changes the x value of `Coord3.zero` to be 5. Maybe I am misunderstanding `readonly`? I know that in Unity there is `Vector3.zero` which never changes. I am trying to achieve the same effect.

Comment: `readonly` means you cannot change 'zero' to point to a different instance of Coord3

Comment: @RyanWilson a const can only be numbers, boolean values or strings

Comment: High odds that Coord3 should be a `struct`.

Comment: Easy, dont allow Coord3 to be mutated. In your case, make the fields of it readonly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe I am misunderstanding `readonly`?

Yeah, `readonly` means you can't change the *reference* of your variable. In other words, you can't write `Coord3.zero = new(...);`

Now, the way [these things are usually written](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector3?view=net-6.0) is as `struct`s, where fields are by default immutable. That would solve your problem right there. That is also how it's done in Unity. Note that you can also do this with classes, by having only getters on your properties and filling them in once from your constructor, but classes are very heavy weight for these small types.

Answer (score 2):

`readonly` is not *quite* the same thing as immutable in the sense you mean. `readonly` means you cannot assign to a variable. So you couldn't do

```cs
public static readonly Cord3 zero = new Cord3(0, 0, 0);

zero = new Cord3(0, 0, 1);
```

In order to achieve the effect you want, you could need to create a class, struct or record with readonly properties or fields. There's no way to achieve that effect with a type defined in an internal library. If the type allows mutability on a field or property, that field or property is mutable.

Answer (score 2):

Marking `zero` as `readonly` indeed prevents you from changing what `zero` stores. You cannot reassign it.

```
zero = new Coord3(1, 1, 1); // error
```

Note that since `Coord3` is a class, `zero.x = 5;` isn't actually changing what `zero` stores. You are just changing some property of the object that `zero` is referring to. `zero` is still storing the same reference to the same old object.

You could prevent this by not providing any public API in `Coord3` that would change its fields' values - for example, by making `x`, `y`, `z` all read-only properties:

```
public int X { get; }
public int Y { get; }
public int Z { get; }
```

Of course, this wouldn't work if you just want to prevent setting the properties on `zero`, but allow the modification of `Coord3` on other objects.

I would suggest that you make `Coord3` a struct:

```
public struct Coord3 {
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }
}
```

Now `zero` stores the fields' values directly, rather than a reference to an object. `zero.x = 5;` would produce an error, because you are modifying what `zero` directly stores.

Note that Unity's [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) for example, is also a struct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make an immutable base class and your `Coord3` inheriting this class.

```cs
public class BaseCoord3
{
    // protected means it can only be used by BaseCoord3 and Coord3
    protected int x;

    // equivalent to public int X { get { return x; } }
    public int X => x;  
}

public class Coord3 : BaseCoord3
{
    public override int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }
    public static BaseCoord3 Zero => new BaseCoord3(0,0,0);
}
```

This should work similar to the way with Readonly versions of collections in c#. I think the struct solutions are the way to go though.

Answer (score 0):

How about you just use a get-property to never change the `zero` object?

```
public class Coord3
{
    public static Coord3 Zero => new Coord3(0,0,0);
}
```

Then you won't be able to change the values of `Zero`, but you will maintain the functionality of `Coord3` objects.

```cs
Coord3 a = Coord3.Zero;
a.x = 2; // changes a.x, but not Coord3.Zero.x
```